# Is it possible to use pandas to create a range of dates with a user-defined frequency higher than 1Hz?

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I would like to use pandas to create a range of dates for geophysical time series with sampling rates up to 2400Hz. I read about the pandas `date_range` method [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html).

Let's assume I have a `data` ndarray containing 15 samples. If I was dealing with a 1Hz sampling rate, I would specify `freq='s'`:

`import pandas as pd`

[...]

`dates=pd.date_range("2014-10-07 05:12:49",periods=data.shape[0], freq='s')`

This would return:

> DatetimeIndex(['2014-10-07 05:12:49', '2014-10-07 05:12:50',
>                  '2014-10-07 05:12:51', '2014-10-07 05:12:52',
>                  '2014-10-07 05:12:53', '2014-10-07 05:12:54',
>                  '2014-10-07 05:12:55', '2014-10-07 05:12:56',
>                  '2014-10-07 05:12:57', '2014-10-07 05:12:58',
>                  '2014-10-07 05:12:59', '2014-10-07 05:13:00',
>                  '2014-10-07 05:13:01', '2014-10-07 05:13:02',
>                  '2014-10-07 05:13:03'],
>                 dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='S')

But what about passing a higher, user-defined sampling rate?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, You can use `ms` as the frequency.

Comment: Hello COLDSPEED! Thanks for your reply! I also noticed that `ms` can be used a the frequency, but what if I want to work with a sampling rate of 15Hz for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how big is your data, you can build it yourself. That would create list of timestamp with a 1 milisecond difference spanning 1 second.

```
t = [pd.Timestamp('2014-10-07') + pd.Timedelta(x, 'ms') for x in range(1000)]
```

You can modify the initial timestamp including hours/minutes/seconds I have used '2014-10-07' plainly.

If you want to modify the frequency then you can add multiples to create a different period (66.67 ms ~ 15Hz)

```
 pd.Timedelta(66.67*x, 'ms')
```

Comment: Hi drublackberry! Thanks for your answer. This did the trick for me! This is how I modified your code to get a 15Hz sampling rate: `t = [pd.Timestamp('2014-10-07 05:12:49') + pd.Timedelta(x/15, 's') for x in range(15)]`

Comment: Yep, better like this since you will use the machine precision for the period. I just wanted to make clear how the period would be inserted in the code.